# PowerPoint Linked to the Excel (SharePoint) Chart refresh & Table issue

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerpoint

I would like to have the Power Point presentation which is automatically updated when data in linked excel are changed. Of course my links to this is the SharePoint Link which looks as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1q2H.png)

It is pointing to the proper data for each chart. I also marked it as "Automatic Update" and links seems to be fine:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL9Zl.png)

However when I make any changes in the excel (changed the value to check the chart) - and press "Update Now" it is not reflected. Chart in Power Point is only updating when I click on the chart (so each chart separately) - and do the "Edit Data" - after that the value on the chart is changing (but I don't want to do this on XX number of charts :d) . Do you have any idea what can be the issue?

Another issue I have is the issue with the table. In my presentation I also have a table which is linked to the excel. I also made it as the "SharePoint link" as per documentation I read (pasted table as a link). But the point is that the link looks like this only until the moment I close the ?excel?:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PS1XY.png)

When I close it (of course it says it is broken) :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAi9W.png)

My aim is to have the presentation which is visible for others (that's why on SharePoint) and for which Chart & Tables point to the excel in which I can do the changes, which then would be automatically populated in the Power Point.

Could you please advise?

Thank you
Ko

I was trying to find any solution, but none of them works (with chart only clicking edit data on each chart allows to really refresh)